# Bash script though webpage to take picture

Tags: php, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, webcam

So I'm trying to run a bash script through a webpage using PHP, (on a raspberry pi if thats relevant). Ordinary commands work fine like 'ls' etc. However when trying to take a picture from the webcam connected to the Pi , using the command:
['fswebcam image.jpg'](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/) it doesn't work at all.

I'm struggling to determine the issue. could it be something to do with permissions?

Taking a picture directly through the terminal works fine.

EDIT:

Sorry about not including this info in the beginning but I'm quite novice at all things web... But I'm using a LEMP stack so I don't have Apache running but using Nginx

Comment: Elaborate on "doesn't work at all".  What error do you get? (Try redirecting `stderr` to a file to take a peek.)  Is there anything in a log such as `/var/log/messages`?  Try to `su` to the user you're running it under (`apache` if the answers are to be believed) and see if you can execute it then.

Comment: I'll check tomorrow what errors messages I can get and make an edit

Comment: I'm getting [UFW BLOCK] error messages in /var/log/messages

Comment: I removed the firewall but from stderr i'm getting the following error message:

1m--- Opening /dev/video0... [0m[0mTrying source module v4l2... [0m[31mError opening device: /dev/video0 [0m[31mopen: Permission denied [0m[0mTrying source module v4l1... [0m[31mError opening device: /dev/video0 [0m[31mopen: Permission denied [0m[31mUnable to find a source module that can read /dev/video0. [0m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, I think also that you are facing permission issue with your hardware on raspberry Pi. As the subject mix raspberry / hardware / linux / web, you read many crap solutions on internet; they often deliver root permission everywhere!

In your case I think that your apache log file (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` ?) will contain the error message, kind of:

```
can not access /dev/vchiq
```

For the moment your apache user (www-data) can not access it:

```
pi$ ls -l /dev/vchiq
crw-rw---T 1 root video 248, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/vchiq
```

Type those commands:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video www-data
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It means that the user www-data will be added in group video (that has access to /dev/vchiq). Then you have to restart your apache server so that it rereads the group file and get informed of the change. Note: you would add www-data to gpio group, if you had to access them from web.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs with apache user permissions.

Does your apache user have permissions to start fswebcam?

```
ll $(which fswebcam)
```

Answer (score 0):

So from the error message I received (posted above) I realised that /dev/video0 needed permissions for other users. so my solution was to just go:

```
chmod 777 /dev/video0
```

It's probably quite a dirty solution but works nonetheless

Comment: see my answer. If ww-data go in video group, he will have access, so you dont need a chmod on /dev/video. I think that the original permission will be restored to /dev/video at reboot.